Repeated Measures Analysis of Variance Question
I have the following data set.
My_Data <- data.frame(Sampling_Date = rep(1:4, each = 12), 
                      Block = rep(1:3, length.out = 48), 
                      Treatment = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3, 
                      length.out = 48), 
                      Response = abs(rnorm(48, 10, 1)))

I'm doing a repeated-measures analysis of variance. Each block contained four plots, where each plot within a block received a different treatment. Plots were repeatedly sampled throughout a year. I'm wondering what the most appropriate way to model these data in R is. Here's what I have so far based on what I've read.
Model <- aov(Response ~ (Treatment * as.factor(Sampling_Date)) + 
                 Error(as.factor(Block) / (Treatment * 
                 as.factor(Sampling_Date))), data = My_Data)
summary(Model)

In this model output, each main effect and interaction term has its own error term, which is essentially the interaction of the main effect or interaction of interest with the blocking (replication) variable.
I have several questions.
First, is the way this model works appropriate? In other words, are these error terms appropriate for each different main effect and interaction? If they are, then why?
Second, do I need to consider a mixed-effects model so I can treat block as a random variable? Since block is essentially just our replication variable, I didn't think it should be included in the model.
Third, when and why should sphericity be taken into account? Does it depend on if we treat sampling date as a numeric or a categorical variable?
Fourth, how would the model change if I were to treat sampling date as a numeric variable?


To the best of my understanding, your model is correct if your goal is to investigate the interaction between treatment and sampling date. As for why the error terms are appropriate, it's because they capture the dependent nature of errors in a within-subject design. See for instance this resource and the Laerd statistics tutorial may also be helpful.

A mixed-effects model would work in principle, and they are generally recommended over RM-ANOVAs anyway. However, if the data you posted is your actual data, then you have too few Block levels to use Block as a random effect. At least 5-6 levels is recommended for a random effect grouping variable to get reliable estimates of random effects.

Sphericity is an assumption for RM-ANOVA, so you should have that to trust your results. R aov does not offer automatic sphericity checks or corrections. The solution to this that I've seen suggested most often is to use the Anova function in the car package. That provides the sphericity test and also Greenhouse-Geisser and Huyhn-Feldt corrections for non-sphericity.

If you put sampling date in as numeric, it will be interpreted as a continuous variable increasing from 1 to 4 (this may depend on the function used though). Its coefficient will reflect the covariation between sampling date (1-4) and Response. Or, when interaction is in the model, it reflects covariation between them in the default treatment group and your interaction cofficients will tell you whether the coefficient of continuous sampling date differs as a function of treatment.
Sphericity is usually (solely?) used to refer to homogeneity of variances between different within-subject conditions in RM-ANOVA. When you have a continuous predictor in a within-subject design, the relevant/corresponding assumption is (I think?) that the continuous predictor does not correlate with the error term. This you can investigate by plotting the residuals vs. fitted for each level of the treatment.


